# Regex to extract text between brackets

Tags: regex

I need to extract the number 5 in the brackets in this HTML code:

```
<td class="th-clr-cel th-clr-td th-clr-pad th-clr-cel-dis" style="width:226px; text-align:left; ">
<span class="th-tx th-tx-value th-tx-nowrap"  style="width:100&#x25;; "  title="Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number&#x20;&#x28;SIN&#x29;" id="C29_W120_V121_builidnumber_table[5].type_text" f2="C;40">
    Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number&#x20;&#x28;SIN&#x29;
</span>
```

This is just an extract of the whole HTML code and there is much more actual code before and after this sample. But one thing is for sure, the word "Insurance" only appears in this sample.

I managed to match whatever is between the 2 instances of "Social Insurance Number" with this regex:

```
((?<=Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number)(.*)(?=Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number))
```

Now I need to combine that and extract the number 5 within the square brackets.

Please note: the content of the bracket could be multiple chracters (i.e.: 15), but it will always be a numeral.

Thank you

EDIT: The reason I want to use regex to parse HTML is because this is part of a JMeter script to run mass performance tests on a system with hundreds of concurrent users. Performance is a major factor here and an XML parser will consume more resources than regex.

Comment: What's the specific problem? The regex for a number contained within other characters? You sure this wouldn't be easier by parsing the HTML?

Comment: Does `.*\[(\d+)\].*` work for you or am I missing something?

Comment: Like I said, there will be tons of code before and after the sample that I posted here. So there will be tons of other brackets and numbers. I need to extract the one that occurs between the 2 instances of the word "Insurance"

Comment: I feel like it's been said a million times, but don't use Regex to parse HTML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: The reason I want to use regex to parse HTML is because this is part of a JMeter script to run mass performance tests on a system with hundreds of concurrent users. Performance is a major factor here and an XML parser will consume more resources than regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Insurance.*\[(\d+)\]
```

Or if you want to match it between the 2x "Insurance" words

```
Insurance.*\[(\d+)\][\s\S]+?Insurance
```

[Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/Zo2Djd/1)

Where

- `Insurance` - Match the starting word "Insurance"
- `.*` - Match any character
- `\[` - Match the opening bracket
- `(\d+)` - Capture the numerical value inside brackets
- `\]` - Match the closing bracket
- `[\s\S]+?` - Match any character (including newlines) in a non-greedy way so that it wouldn't span across multiple "Insurance" words
- `Insurance` - Match the ending word "Insurance"

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. This is very clean

Answer (score 2):

This will capture exactly digits under square brackets surrounded by term Insurance:

```
Insurance(?:[\s\S]*)\[(\d+)\](?:[\s\S]*)Insurance
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/hwFB0Y/3

Comment: Using `(?:.|\n)*` is a bit inefficient due to the alternation. You can use `[\s\S]*` instead or if supported use an inline modifier `(?s)` to have the dot match a newline. Javascript supports `[^]*`

Comment: Thank you @Thefourthbird!! Found this platform best only because of people like you. Learning++

Comment: In the character class, the `|` does not mean OR, it means matching a pipe char. But `[\s|\S]*` is unnecessary as `\s` and `\S` already match everything including a pipe :-)

Comment: Thank you once again!! You cleared some of my ongoing doubts.

Comment: Thank you both! Another good solution. I would have marked it as the answer, but the other one was posted before this one.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
((?<=Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number.*\[)(\d+)(?=\].*Social&#x20;Insurance&#x20;Number))
```

Comment: It's giving me an error when I test it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Some regex engines support non-fixed lookbehinds.